# how to solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException

Tags: java, http, apache-camel, apache-karaf, hawtio

I'm using apache-camel and this is my first deployment of a bundle to karaf. I want to catch `HttpOperationFailedException`:

```
<doCatch id="catch-http_request">
  <exception>org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException</exception>
  <to id="prepareRespAcc_http" uri="bean:com.ngtrend.lcmwbmadmin.WBResponseHandler?method=prepareResponseAcc(400,${body})"/> 
  <log id="log-wb-account-params" loggingLevel="INFO" message="wbm admin query params: ${body}"/>
  <log id="log-catch-http-error" loggingLevel="ERROR" message="Sending bad Request : ${exception.message}"/>  
</doCatch>
```

apache_karaf shows this error :
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException`

Comment: i think apache karaf has a problem with this exception

Comment: you asked pretty much the same question a day before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62133287/camel-catch-httpoperationfailedexception

Answer (score 0):

The class is part of the http components. When it is not found, typically the camel-http4 component is not on the classpath. Does your karaf bundle include this component?

Since you want to catch this exception, I assume you do HTTP calls in your bundle. How do you do these calls? Not with camel?

Comment: my karaf bundle doesn t include camel-http4 . and this is the code for calling http `<to id="create-wb account" uri="jetty:http://{{wb.ip}}:{{wb.port}}/{{wb.path}}?httpMethod=POST&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>`

Comment: You should not use the [Jetty component](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/jetty-component.html) as a producer. It was deprecated in Camel 2.x and removed in Camel 3.x.

Comment: camel-jetty depends on camel-http-common and this jar contains the class in question. Is this dependency included in your bundle?

Comment: i added camel-http-common in my bundle and karaf web console shows `Instance not found: org.apache.camel:context=LCM-WBM-ADMIN-camelContext-WBM-ADMIN,type=context,name="camelContext-WBM-ADMIN"`

Comment: Looks like a JMX problem. You could try to disable [Camels JMX instrumentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/jmx.html)

Comment: Thank you "burki" for the link.

Comment: I disabled JMX by adding this line of code `<jmxAgent id="agent" disabled="true"/>` and i didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I know pretty much nothing about your environment and bundle build. You obviously use camel-jetty and this component has dependencies. You should not just add a single Jar, but the dependencies should ALL be added to your bundle. if camel-http-common was not part of your bundle, this dependency mechanism does not work and you have to make it work. You cannot manage every single jar manually.

Comment: I'm using camel 2.24.3 and maven version 3.2.0,and this is my liste of dependencies: **asm-commons/camel-core/camel-blueprint/camel-cxf/camel-jetty/camel-http/camel-http-common/json/cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/org.osgi.service.http/slf4j-log4j12/camel-test-blueprint**